# How to plot an histogram with matplotlib using python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have 2 lists:

```
    X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15] 
    Y = [0.5717, 0.699, 0.7243, 0.5939, 0.5383, 0.5093, 0.7001, 0.589, 0.6486, 0.7152, 0.6805, 0.5688, 0.6133, 0.6041, 0.5676].
    plt.xlabel('X')
    plt.ylabel('Y'))
    plt.title("Histogram")
    xbins = [x for x in range(len(Xaxis))]
    numBins = len(Xaxis)
    plt.hist(Xaxis,xbins ,color='green',alpha=0.6)
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

When I am doing like this i am not getting correctly.so if i  want to plot an histogram using this data. How can I do that using python programming?

Comment: @sinhayash I have checked various examples and tried but that doent solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but I'll give it a shot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15] 
Y = [0.5717, 0.699, 0.7243, 0.5939, 0.5383, 0.5093, 0.7001, 0.589, 0.6486, 0.7152, 0.6805, 0.5688, 0.6133, 0.6041, 0.5676]
plt.bar(X, Y, color='green', alpha=0.6, align='center')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.title("Histogram")
plt.show()
```

Is that the plot you are looking for? If not, please provide more details.
[image]

Comment: I did the the bar graph and it is working fine for me. My doubt is can i be able to draw a histogram using 2 lists?

Comment: I'm afraid that for the data you have provided, it would make no sense to create a histogram, be it one- or two-dimensional.

Comment: Ok Thank you. After plotting a graph if i move the mouse over the graph i want to display the values.How can i do that?